# Pandas equivalent to SQL VIEW

Tags: python, view, pandas

Is there an easy way to generate an object in pandas which acts like a DataFrame except some or all of the columns are virtual, similar to a database view? The particular problem I have in mind is creating a few convenience columns which are simple functions of one or two other columns (adding, subtracting, multiplying by a constant etc). The number of rows can reach tens of millions so the memory overhead of adding another column of data is non-trivial.

I know this can be done by subclassing DataFrame and overriding **getitem** (and probably all sorts of other functions in the internals), but is there an easier way that I have missed?

Comment: your question is very similar to this one: ttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024742/how-to-store-formulas-instead-of-values-in-pandas-dataframe , what would would do with these columns other than create them?